# getting the check if twitch stream is live

Tags: java, json, twitch

I have been working with java to make it where i check if a certain user if live and it will say true or false if the user is streaming...im working with minimal json.

here is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;


public class hostbot {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Twitchbot bot = new Twitchbot();
    bot.setVerbose(true);
    bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "something");
 }
 public boolean isStreamLive()
   {
     try 
         {
           URL url = new        URL("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/rexephon");
           URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ));
           String inputLine = br.readLine();
           br.close();
           JsonObject jsonObj = JsonObject.readFrom(inputLine);
           return ( jsonObj.get("stream").isNull() )?false:true;
          } 
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
    return false; 
}
}
```

when i return false is that suppose to print in the log the word false? or something else?

Comment: You might want to learn some basics of Java. `return false` means the function will return when you call it. 

If you want to try printing it, you might be able to do `System.out.println(isStreamLive());` This would be called in your `main` function.

Comment: Thank you man! I know im still learning basic java.... im not the smartest person but im trying.  but still thank you man!

Comment: Of course :) Feel free to post more questions if you have any!

Comment: yeah i have a question and about to post it!